# How can I compile bootstrap.min.js excluding unused Javascript plugins?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I would like to compile the Bootstrap source `bootstrap.min.js` to exclude unused Javascript plugins in order to reduce the KB size of the file, and create a new file containing only the used plugins.

Let's say i currently, only use `offcanvas.js` and `dropdown.js`: how can i remove all js modules (alert.js, button.js, carousel.js, toast.js and all others) from the `botstrap.min.js` file, and remain in it only offcanvas.js and dropdown.js?

Bootstrap suggest two ways [Lean JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript) or [Webpack and bundler](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/webpack/), but I failed to apply them. I believe the mechanism is the same as SASS compiling the SCSS file to CSS (which i did fine correctly), or maybe not, but for the Javascript i fail.

My idea (i don't know if it's good, maybe there are other best ways) is to create a file where i only import offcanvas.js and dropdown.js. Next compile it and then create `my.bootstrap.min.js`

Can anyone show me a practical example please? Thank you all for help!!!

Comment: JS modules are nowhere near SASS. SASS needs to compile server-sided to CSS while modules do not need to be compiled at all just included on the client side. On a very basic level, it is just another JS file for abstracting modules to re-use multiple times on multiple files. The tweak you trying to do is not worth the effort as the files are only loaded once and going to be cached and the internet is not as sloq as 30 years ago

Comment: @tacoshy I know internet is not as slow as many years ago, but I need to reduce js file size for SEO reasons related to google scoring. Now bootstrap.min.js is 60.3KB. I know it's quite small, but I'd like to make it even smaller. Why should I have a file full of code for plugins I don't use? (it's a rhetorical question). You say it's not worth doing, okay you are right, but I want to do it anyway. Could you help me please? Thank you

Comment: at this point, it won't influence the SEO rating anymore. The SEO ratings take the size mainly for media such as images and video into account. However, not files that are a small kb size. For your other question, why should you use a framework over custom CSS when you not going to use the framework for its actual usage (providing solutions for most cases without needing in-depth knowledge in advanced coding)?

Comment: @tacoshy If you say that SEO evaluations only consider the size mainly for average, does that mean that the size of the HTML, CSS and JS files doesn't matter either? I knew their size was important for SEO. I knew that the higher the loading and opening speed of a site (thanks to a small KB of html, css and js code)...the higher the Google score (apart from all other different evaluation factors). Are you 100% sure?

Comment: I didn't say that it does not take CSS and JS into account just not at such low size. Media files are mainly taken into account as the about 100 times larger and usually are not only one file.

Comment: @tacoshy So Google "accounts for size". We're both in agreement on this :) Now I was thinking "if Google factor in size, even a 60.3KB JS file might affect it. It'll have little impact, but it might affect it." Unfortunately there isn't someone/something that can answer us with certainty. Anyway, even if you don't agree with my thinking, I don't want to go outside the question. Could you still help me with the question I asked? Thank you

Comment: This relevant page in the docs shows how you can just comment out the components you don't need before compiling: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/. @tacoshy it's still worth the effort to exclude unused scripts. Millions of people still don't have high speed internet access.

Comment: @Sean This is the same page I copied into a link of my question. Talk about Lean Sass for the CSS, which I managed to get it right down. And then talk about Lean Javascript, as I reported in the question. This is exactly what I don't understand and I wanted some help with this. For Lean Sass I had no problems, but for Lean Javascript I really don't know how to do it. Where should I write those things? Could you help me explaining better how to do it?

Comment: Just like when you asked this question 3 days ago before you deleted it again: Don't. 80k is not worth reducing. If it were 800kb, maybe but 80kb is not worth your time. Spend that time on your project instead.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Okay fine, sorry. I remember your suggestion, but I would like to reduce the file anyway. For me now it has become a matter of principle, I am determined to do it. Also on the Bootstrap site it talks about shrinking the js file. I don't think mine is such a pointless question. As in the other comment, I asked you if you could help me, but then you didn't answer anymore. Would you be so kind and able to help me and answer my question please? Thank you

Comment: Then hopefully someone will answer this for you. Just don't delete it and then repost it a few days later again. But the https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize link pretty much covers it already from what I can tell. Instead of using the prebuilt .min JS file, install bootstrap, and only import the CSS you need on the CSS side, and only import the JS parts you need on the JS side. Then let your bundler sort out the rest.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I asked you twice (in different questions) if you were so kind and able to help me: once you didn't answer me, while now you avoided and deflected the reply of the comment. Okay, I accept it. I understand that you don't want to help me, don't worry, maybe you're bored, or you don't have time, or you're not capable :) But it's not nice to comment on me twice, and in both cases, just to say that it's not worth solving the problem of my question. That way, you don't help people. Won't you help me? Ok, fine, but don't comment just to say it's not worth what I asked.

Comment: Don't try to doctor the .min.js file. Import what you need directly in your own code, and then your own bundler (whether that's webpack, or esbuild, or some other bundler) does the rest, where it will only import what you're actually using, and nothing more.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  I read that you have modified the comment above, adding to the comment, later, some minimal hints of help. I downloaded the Bootstrap folder (without installing it). Then I created a custom.scss file and inside I imported only the css components I needed, then I converted to css. Now it was Javascript's turn, but I couldn't. Perhaps you meant a different procedure in the comment. What do you mean by "ninstall bootstrap and import only the CSS you need on the CSS side and import only the JS parts you need on the JS side"?

Comment: Don't download the files manually, install it into your project using `npm` (or `yarn`), like any other dependency (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers).

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  I've never installed it directly into the project. What would it change? What benefits would I have in relation to my question?

Comment: it changes the part where the "lean JS" part that's confusing you is no longer confusing. Like everything else JS related, you import the bootstrap parts you want, using plain JS import statements in your app index. So: install bootstrap, and then write the imports you need using the syntax that Bootstrap shows you in its "optimizing" documentation. And then your bundler will _only_ include those parts, and nothing else, when it bundles up your app.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  Are you referring to, for example, import Modal from 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal' or import "modal";?

Comment: The code you see in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-javascript, so no: ignore `dist` _completely_.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans  Ok, now I try. So I screwed up Bootstrap installation and consequences ensued. Thank you. Instead "Default Exports" I don't need right? Thank you

Comment: no default imports, only the specific ones you actually need.

Comment: I think the original question should have been focused on how to properly set up javascript bundling, since it was demonstrably possible to selectively exclude js components in the docs.

Comment: @Sean What do you mean by "demonstrably possible to selectively exclude js components in the docs"? Please explain better. Thank you

Comment: On the page I linked to, the docs explain how to exclude unused js components while bundling. So the question should have been about how to get bundling working.